# save a chart together a txt file with savedialog

Tags: c#, charts, savefiledialog

I have a `listbox`, I save it to a txt file with following code.

```
            String[] array = new String[listBox2.Items.Count];
            listBox2.Items.CopyTo(array, 0);
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "per_" ;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (.txt)|*.txt";

            Nullable<bool> res = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (res == true)
            {
                string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

                File.WriteAllLines(filename, array, Encoding.UTF8);

                MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully");
            }
```

I save chart to c://

```
chart2.SaveImage("C://", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

However I want to save my chart at same direction which user chosed with `savefiledialog`. What should I do to manage this?

Comment: or is it possible add listbox and jpeg into a pdf in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
chart2.SaveImage(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

or this

```
chart2.SaveImage(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName) + "\\chart.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

if SaveImage method needs a filename